# What does declaration of an object element in a class mean?

Tags: java, linked-list, abstract, abstract-data-type

As far as what I've studied is that we create an instance of a class using the constructor of the class.

```
ClassName obj=new ClassName(parameters);
```

However I came across a program trying to describe Linked list in Java using the following class ChainNode

```
class ChainNode
{
  Object element; //What does this mean?
  ChainNode nxt;
  ChainNode(Object element)
  {
   this.element=element;
  }
  ChainNode(Object elem, ChainNode nxt)
  {
   this.element=elem;
   this.next=nxt;
  }
}
```

Comment: It isn't an 'object element'. It is a *reference.*

Comment: Can you please explain that in detail in an answer?

Comment: `Object element` simple means an `Object` with the name `element`. It could have been `Object withAnyNameYouLike` .

Answer (score 0):

Your first statement is correct and also applies to the `ChainNode` class. The reason you see a `ChainNode` **member variable** inside the `ChainNode` class definition is because of the LinkedList structure: The *ith* item in the list points to the *(i + 1)th* item. The `ChainNode` inside the class just says that each `ChainNode` object references another `ChainNode` object.

So in this case, you would define your ChainNodes like this:

```
ChainNode node2 = new ChainNode("Item 2");
ChainNode node1 = new ChainNode("Item 1", node2);
```

Notice how when we made `node1`, we pass in `node2` as the next reference. Also notice that if you don't pass in a next reference for node2, it will default to `null`. We now have a basic linked list:

"Node 1" --> "Node 2" --> null

Answer (score 0):

Object is a parent class of all the classed we define in java. In simple terms, the statement "Object element;" is similar to "String abc".

Just like we define abc as a String, we are defining an element of type Object. As Object (with a capital O) is a super class of all the other classes in Java, object of any class And any other object can be assigned to element.

Eg:

```
   Object element;
   element = studentObject;
   element = ArrayListObject;
```

So in your example, you must be calling a ChainNode constructor in a child class by passing an object of any other class, may be something like 'Node' class as you are implementing a linked list.

```
Object element; //What does this mean?
ChainNode nxt;
ChainNode(Object element)
{
    this.element=element;
}
```